# .desktop file in xsessions folder not autorunning

Tags: autostart, .desktop, kiosk, lxsession

I was setting up a kiosk per this tutorial http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-Up-Ubuntu-as-a-Kiosk-Web-Appliance/?ALLSTEPS

I have hit a problem with the kiosk.desktop file since it is not autorunning when i login to the kiosk account. I cannot figure out why. I have spent extensive hours googling the problem from several angles and am at a point where I can't get it without help.

my kiosk.desktop file is located at /usr/share/xsessions/kiosk.desktop and it reads as follows.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Kiosk Mode
Comment=Chromium Kiosk Mode
Exec=/usr/share/xsessions/chromeKiosk.sh
Type=Application
```

do I have any typos or something that is wrong in that regard? I have also included my bash file to see if the problem is there not with the .desktop file.

```
#!/bin/bash
xscreensaver -nosplash &
width=`xrandr | grep \* | head -n1 | cut -d' ' -f4 | cut -d'x' -f1` 
height=`xrandr | grep \* | head -n1 | cut -d' ' -f4 | cut -d'x' -f2` 

echo $width,$height 

cat ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences | perl -pe     "s/\"work_area_bottom.*/\"work_area_bottom\": $height,/" > /tmp/tmp.$$ 
cp /tmp/tmp.$$ ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences 
cat ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences | perl -pe "s/\"bottom.*/\"bottom\":     $height,/" > /tmp/tmp.$$ 
cp /tmp/tmp.$$ ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences 
cat ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences | perl -pe     "s/\"work_area_right.*/\"work_area_right\": $width,/" > /tmp/tmp.$$ 
cp /tmp/tmp.$$ ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences 
cat ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences | perl -pe "s/\"right.*/\"right\": $width,/"     > /tmp/tmp.$$ 
mv /tmp/tmp.$$ ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
while true; do chromium-browser %u --kiosk --start-maximized; sleep 5s; done
```

Comment: I navigated to the kiosk.desktop file in my file browser and executed it. It worked to launch a chrome kiosk but didn't autorun like it was supposed to. I set a link to this in the startup applications that runs it on startup. THIS IS A HACKED SOLUTION AND NOT WHAT I WAS LOOKING FOR.

Answer (score -1):

probably your script does not have execute permissions

```
chmod 755 /usr/share/xsessions/chromeKiosk.sh
```